# Default texturecoordinates on MeshGeometry3D

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

Is it possible(Without looping through all texturecoordinates) to set them as 0 as default?

I am creating a linear gradient ImageBrush

```
var colorBitmap = GetColorsBitmap(gradient.ToList()); // Create Colors from gray to my selected color
        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(colorBitmap)
        {
            ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
            Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1) // Matches the pixels in the bitmap.
        };
myModel.Material = new DiffuseMaterial(ib);
```

Then depending on a condition I customize some of the Texturecoordinates like this, where colorvalue is the distance from an object:

```
var mesh = (MeshGeometry3D) myModel.Geometry;

//In a loop, depending on the distance I set a colorValue
mesh.TextureCoordinates[count] = new Point(colorValue, 0);
```

I want every texturecoordinate to default to a Point(0,0) but if I have to loop through all 1.2 million of them takes too much time. So is there a way to setup my ImageBrush so that they default to 0,0 or something similiar?

Comment: How are you creating your mesh? Can you set thd texture coordinates to zero as you are creating the vertices etc? Alternatively, looping through 1.2 million texture coordinates might not take too long if it's a one time action.

Comment: @AlBal mesh is loaded from an STL using
var myModel = new ModelImporter().Load(modelBytes).Children[0] as GeometryModel3D

I would prefer to be able to do it "live", the shorter delay the better that is why when applying the brush if each texturecoordinate x=0 from the start I only need to change about 5% of the model which is fast.

Comment: stlreader adds texture coordinates when it creates the mesh. By default it uses texture coordinate (0,0), (1,0), and (0,1) for the nodes of each triangle it adds to the mesh. I haven't found a way previouslybto change this behaviour. Changing the brush doesn't affect the texture coordinates. You could extend the meshbuilder class to include a method that assigns (0,0) to each node by default?

Comment: I will try that. I need to re-apply the brush multiple times throughout the lifetime of the model (basically resetting) the texture so might mess that up but I will try.

Other suggestion was to use some sort of shader through SharpDx, which seem awefully complicated as it doesn't seem to be well documented and it is also not maintained anymore.